# JSDoc: How to specify any type except one

Tags: javascript, types, documentation, jsdoc

## How do I exclude a type in JSDoc?

In my code, I have built a function that flattens an array. The input type is `Array<*>` (an array filled with anything) but for the output, **I want to exclude the type `Array`**. However, I can't find any information in the JSDoc documentation for `@type` about excluding types.

Essentially I want something like:

```
@returns {Array<* except Array>}
```

Does that exist or should I bring this up as an issue on the JSDoc GitHub repo?

Comment: Why exactly do you want to exclude array?

Comment: @GrahamPHeath because the end array will have no arrays inside of it, as it has been flattened.